# Using Cauchy Integral, solve: $\oint_C \frac{1}{(2z+1)^2}dz$ without use residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

C is a unitary circle.

If I simplify, I get:  $\oint_C \frac{1/2}{(z+1/2)(z+1/2)}$
How can i solve? If I use Cauchy Integral Theorem, $z_0 = -1/2$ and f(z) = 2, so answer is $2\pi i * (-1/2)$?

Idk how to solve with 1/(z-a)^n

Comment: Maybe "Cauchy Integral Theorem" means $${\displaystyle f^{(n)}(a)={\frac {n!}{2\pi i}}\oint _{\gamma }{\frac {f(z)}{\left(z-a\right)^{n+1}}}\,dz}$$

Comment: Where did you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the logarithm, $-\tfrac{1/2}{2z+1}$ doesn't have branches, so an integral of $\tfrac{1}{(2z+1)^2}$ around a closed loop is $0$.

Comment: But it cannot be 0, because the circle is unitary so at z = -1 / 2 we have a hole that is inside the circle. Right?

Comment: @Klein You mean a *pole*. Ah, but what's the integrand's $\tfrac{1}{2z+1}$ coefficient, when it's construed as a Laurent series? It's $0$.

Comment: Thanks for correct me.
I thought that any function that has a pole inside the closed loop, the result would be something like 2$\pi$ i. 
So in these cases, do I need to do the Laurent series to evaluate?